# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Operation not supported for this Channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I use this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/api/channel-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp.

I get this message, when I want to add member in channel [enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gude.png)

```
 var conversationMember = new AadUserConversationMember
            {
                Roles = new List<String>()
                {

                },
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {userBind, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{userId}')"}
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Teams[$"{teamId}"].Channels[$"{channelId}"].Members
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(conversationMember);// Here I get error
```

I created channel here

```
            var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = department.Name,
                Channels = new TeamChannelsCollectionPage()
                {

                },
                Members = new TeamMembersCollectionPage()
                {
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            { userBind, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{ownerId}')" }
                        },
                    }
                },

                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { templateBind, urlTeamsApiStandard },
                }
            };

            foreach (var bitrixChannel in department.Channels)
            {
                var channel = new Channel
                {
                    DisplayName = bitrixChannel.Name,
                    MembershipType = ChannelMemberShipType.Private // Here I choose private, which doesnt work
                };

                team.Channels.Add(channel);
            }

            await graphClient.Teams
                     .Request()
                     .AddAsync(team);
```

What is wrong?

**UPD:**
I found that my channels in ms teams creates in not private mode, even if I choosed private. But I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to use

```
await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels
                 .Request()
                     .AddAsync(channel);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding conversationMember to the channel, this operation is only allowed for channels with a **membershipType** value **private** which explains the error.

Comment: I'm tried this, didn't help

Comment: Again, please refrain from asking for votes. I have downvoted on this occasion, as this has been edited out of your material many times.